# How to set dynamically the yesterday date starting from 00:00 in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to dynamically set in mysql this:

`2017-07-26 00:00:00`

for yesterday's time, like I do with `now()` for now.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's `DATE` function to extract date part from datetime, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW());
```

This will give you current date without time.

If you want yesterday's date, you can use `DATE_ADD` to subtract 1 day and use `DATE` function on the result to get the date without time, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY));
```

Here's the documentation for [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) functions.

**Update**

If you want seconds as `00:00:00` then you can use `CONCAT` method, e.g.:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)), ' 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Hi, but I want the 00:00:00 also

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TIMESTAMP()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) to convert a date to a timestamp with `00:00:00` as time part:

```
select timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day);
```